# How to re-use $.when() with Deferred

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

I would like to reuse a jQuery Deferred. HTML:

```
<form id="theForm" class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post">
    <div class="form-actions">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Do Something</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
var aDeferred = $.Deferred();

var doSomething = function () {
    console.log('in doSomething');
    aDeferred.resolve();
    console.log('state after resolving: ' + aDeferred.state());
}

$('#theForm').submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('state in submit: ' + aDeferred.state());
    doSomething();
});

$.when(aDeferred).done(function () {
    console.log('we are done');
    aDeferred = $.Deferred();
});
```

-> [jsFidlle](http://jsfiddle.net/philcms1/td7ptrto/)

The first time the button is clicked, I understand the sequence:

```
state in submit: pending
in doSomething
we are done
state after resolving: pending
```

But after the first click, although the deferred is resolved, `$.when().done()` is not executed anymore.

```
state in submit: pending
in doSomething
state after resolving: resolved
```

However, if I move `$.when()` in the submit function, it works fine:

```
$('#theForm').submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('state in submit: ' + aDeferred.state());
    doSomething();

    $.when(aDeferred).done(function () {
        console.log('we are done');
        aDeferred = $.Deferred();
    });
});
```

Could someone explain why?

Comment: it isn't possible to resolve (or reject) a promise more than once. Use a callback instead.

Comment: FYI, `$.when()` is only useful when you have more than one promise.  If you have just one promise or deferred, then just call `.done()` directly on it - `$.when()` is not needed in that case.  As Kevin said, a promise can only be fullfilled once.  After that, you have to make a new promise or just use a callback to trigger again.  If you want repeatedly be notified of an event, a promise is the wrong tool.

Comment: @KevinB -- could you demonstrate how to use a callback? In my actual code, `doSomething` invokes a restful API.

Comment: Allow doSomething to accept a callback, and execute the callback in the complete callback of the request to the restful API.

Comment: Though, normally, requests to restful apis result in promise objects. How are you making said request? $.ajax?

Comment: @KevinB The request is made by a third-party API, and executes a callback: `apiObj.apiCall(function(data, err) { // callback });`